# Java2d OpenGL BlackScreen

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jframe

I'm using Eclipse to code, my program worked every time fine but after a new Windows Update my program isn't working anymore I only get a Black `JFrame` but the console works right and I found the problem line:

```
    'System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "True");'
```

if I change it to

```
    'System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "False");'
```

Everything works but the whole program begin to lag , thanks for all helpful answers

Comment: Install or reinstall the latest version of the graphics driver.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I had already updated my graphics driver and also reinstalled both didn't work but thanks for your help

Comment: What is your java sdk version ? and setting it to false will definately make your application lag as you dont have any hardware acceleration.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni I'm using jdk1.7.0_55 .